# Is the word Desultory used frequently?

Tags: word-usage

Today in my writing class I wrote: *a desultory conversation*, then I was told the word desultory is so rarely used and I should avoid using these kind of words in my academic writing.

I want to ask if I can use this word in my writing or my essay at all?

Comment: Depends on your field. If you are studying literature, maybe. A significant majority of English speakers will not understand it.

Comment: Avoid in academic writing? If academics don't understand it, who will?

Comment: In Britain, 'desultory' is not considered rare or archaic, and a 'significant majority' of people would definitely understand it.

Comment: thanks for the reply first, we were doing some paraphrasing in class today, the text was "the biggest type of error leads to misunderstanding or a total breakdown in communication." I didn't know why the word desultory just popped out, i wrote something like: the most prominent error may contribute to a desultory conversation, I'm not really good at paraphrasing but I just want to ask you guys about this word first, then perhaps you can also give me some advice on this paraphrase.

Comment: Angyang, it sounds like you don't really understand what 'desultory' means.